# Server backdoor via Internet

Tags: server, remote, remote-access

I'm installing a number of machines into an overseas site, and I am fearful that I might get cut out after the machines are up and running.

I'd like to install a backdoor into Ubuntu server so I can gain access if I do get screwed over.

Is there any way I can connect, without knowing the external IP address, without having the firewall forwarding ports etc?

Comment: This sounds very illegal. You want to leave a backdoor, that anyone could exploit, in some companys network? Sounds to me like it is them who will get screwed over.

Comment: How legal or illegal is it? Does your employee know what you are up to?

Comment: Yes it can be done, but I doubt anyone here is going to be comfortable with explaining how to do so.

Comment: "Is there any way I can connect, without knowing the external IP address" No.

Comment: It's not illegal.  I'm installing servers for a company that I'm 'meant to be' a partner in.  No contracts signed yet, so I'm getting nervous.

All I want to know is 'is there a way I can SSH style connect to a server without a firewall port 22 being forwarded?'

Comment: @PrestonCole Just don't do any work until you received your contract. That's the way it works, period.

Comment: @PrestonCole don't give them admin access yet. Do give them a couple hours to test that you provided what you promised...before you depart the data center. Alternately, since you seem to outside the USA and working with a shady customer, another option is to cut your losses and abandon the project now.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). It looks like you actually mean to ask "How I can I assure that my client isn't going to screw me out of my payment when I hand over access to the prepared systems for testing?" Could you please [edit] your question to clarify what you *actually* want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for out-of-band server management tools, often also referred to as **Lights-Out Management**.

Some server manufacturers will bundle LOM systems with their servers (for example, HP provides [iLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out)). Some processors  will come with something a simialar solution (for example, [Intel AMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology)), which will provide effectively the same level of access to a server.

If a provider does not bundle this solution, you will need to look at a KVM-based solution such as [IPKVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch#KVM_over_IP_.28IPKVM.29). The vast majority of IPKVM solutions will only require a display connector and a couple USB ports on the host device.

No solution will be perfect or turnkey. There is a decent amount of configuration that must be done with any of these, and all of these solutions have upsides and downsides. It is the responsibility of the IT provider and the IT departments involved to find and build a workable solution that meets all requirements. Most IT departments will be extremely happy to have a LOM solution built into their servers due to the ability to manage them and run remote maintenance.

With all of this in mind, it's important to know that these are still restricted. The external IP address of the lights-out provider will still need to be known. The router or network-level firewall must still allow connections to it.

Note that out-of-band solutions are by no means "hidden." They are very easy to spot if one knows what they're looking for, and are designed this way. I would advise very strongly against attempting to install such a solution without informing the network administrators (or other high-ranking IT staff) ahead of time. The network may require additional configuration to support LOM and ensure that any lights-out solution is secure from external threat.

---

If out-of-band solutions are not an option, one must stick with an in-band solution such as SSH or any other standard remote management solution.

This, unfortunately, has the downside of requiring the operating system to be online and actually work. Therefore, if the OS is misconfigured or problems occur in the configuration, one may be locked out of the server entirely.

---

This, of course, still assumes you know IP addresses or they are otherwise static. If this is not the case, you must implement some form of dynamic IP solution. Things like [NoIP](https://www.noip.com) will allow you to assign a hostname to a server and will allow you to completely bypass issues such as the public-facing IP address changing.

I've personally used Cloudflare's DNS solution to solve this issue. Every server (on boot, or every 24 hours) will publish a DNS record to `$thathostname.internal.example.com` so that I can access them by hostname, regardless of current DHCP settings.

No matter the case, a firewall must still be open somewhere on the line. No solution (either in- or out-of-band) will be able to operate with a firewall standing in the way. And, just like there's no way to remote into an airgapped computer, there's no way to get through a properly-designed (meaning both inbound and outbound) firewall.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Kaz, but the hardware does not come with/support a lights out style solution.

Comment: @PrestonCole IPKVM switches require (usually) only a VGA and USB port on the host computer, and a single outbound connection to the LAN or global internet. If this is not an option, you'll have to rely on in-band solutions which are very prone to failure and do not offer redundancy or access in case of emergency (such as OS failure).

Comment: No way you know of to all SSH style access without forwarding ports via a firewall?

Comment: @PrestonCole There are definitely some solutions like this. However, depending on your network configuration (e.g. if an outbound firewall exists), these can also fail. Really, though, if you need remote access you can just punch a hole in the existing firewall or have your network administrator do that for you.

Comment: My concern is that the firewall will get closed after I've installed and left the country

Comment: @PrestonCole Unless you have a maintenance contract with this company, I'd not worry about it. You installed the servers, you got paid. Them enabling a firewall would even be an excuse for you to *not* give them free maintenance.

Comment: I didn't say I got paid yet.  Contracts not signed.  Deadline for installing is very soon, and I'm getting a little on edge, so want to protect myself a bit

Comment: @PrestonCole Ah, I see the issue you're dealing with. Everything makes a lot more sense now, to be honest. If you can't get paid in advance for your work, I'd recommend either demanding you be paid in advance, or ensure that you get paid before you leave the datacenter. Get a contract (at the very least) before you do *any* work. Regrettably, there's no software (or hardware) solution you can use that is 100% effective here. This is more of a people problem that, regrettably, can't be solved with technology.

Comment: Cheers Kaz, I'll keep searching

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i understand what you're trying to do. But maybe you should reword your question so it doesn't sound illegal.

If you are ***genuinely*** the administrator of this server and you don't have a UI on the server, SSH as far as i know is the best way to go and yes you will need to open ports no matter what ***unless*** you connect your ubuntu server to a VPN and both your remote PC is also connected to the VPN, then you can access it that way with something free like [Hamachi](https://www.vpn.net/). Alternatively, if you *have* a UI you can use a remote software like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) or [ScreenConnect](https://www.connectwise.com/resources/trial/screenconnect-now-connectwise-control?source=CW-WebRef-ScreenConnect-Trial-All-2017&utm_source=screenconnect&utm_medium=webref&utm_campaign=trial) (Trial) and maybe [ChromeRemoteDesktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en) to connect to the server whenever you need access.

Next time if you need to gain access to a server at work and your boss is completely aware that you will be doing this and has approved such action, please refer to it as *"Remote Administration"*. Saying that you need a *"backdoor"* makes it sound like you're up to something malicious.

So:

- SSH: Requires open ports but its a build in tool.
- VPN + SSH: Third party software and wont require open ports
- Remote Control: No Open ports but requires third party software.

Comment: Note that systems like Hamachi and TeamViewer are not exactly "free." They are free for personal use only, and are not approved for corporate use. If this is desired, a license will need to be bought from the appropriate party. Either way, Remote Access systems are still dependent on a firewall - if outbound connections are restricted (like any secure network should be), these solutions ***will*** fail.

Comment: open ssh and vnc can be a good choice.but guys the question already looks kind of fishy

Comment: Wouldn't openssh and vnc require a port or two to be forwarded to a host on the inside?

Fishy it is not.

Comment: Thank xR34P3Rx,
I know how it sounds, and I'll not bust a gut trying to convince anyone.
Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Hey xR34P3Rx, thanks for the tips.
I didn't know of Hamachi.  I use logmein, but was unaware of the vpn service, and had no clue it'd work with a command line only OS.
I'm all good now.
I expect all will work out, but this will help me sleep at night.

Cheers

Comment: If my suggestions fixed your issue, I'd like to be selected as answer :)

Comment: Thinking in perspective of network security it looks like you are creating a botnet  in a remote server which currently you have full access to and installing a trojan so as to form a botnet.  Even in that case the firewall or ufw rules should be defined so as to forward request to you. You can surely use the system remotely if you know the GUID of the system. If you are really the sys admin for the server then you can build any connection port/get request/etc so as to remotely activate connection to your system whenever a reuest is send.

Comment: read one of these, its kind of similar to what you are suggesting. https://thehackernews.com/2013/10/unauthorized-access-backdoor-found-in-d.html